# Python - CSV to Matrix

Tags: python, csv, matrix

Can you help me with this problem?

I`m new in programming and want to find out how to create a matrix, which looks like this:

```
matrix = {"hello":["one","two","three"],
          "world": ["five","six","seven"],
          "goodbye":["one","two","three"]}
```

I want to import a csv, which has all the strings (one, two three,...) in it and I tried with the split method, but I`m not getting there...
Another problems are the names of the categories (hello, world, goodbye)

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You will increase the change to get a good answer if you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For example, add sample content of your csv file.

Comment: first of all the data structre you cited is not a matrix, it is a dictionary, could you show how your csv looks like and how you read it?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into the csv module?
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
import csv

TEST_TEXT = """\
hello,one,two,three
world,four,five,six
goodbye,one,two,three"""

TEST_FILE = TEST_TEXT.split("\n")
#file objects iterate over newlines anyway
#so this is how it would be when opening a file

#this would be the minimum needed to use the csv reader object:
for row in csv.reader(TEST_FILE):
    print(row)

#or to get a list of all the rows you can use this:
as_list = list(csv.reader(TEST_FILE))

#splitting off the first element and using it as the key in a dictionary
dict_I_call_matrix = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in csv.reader(TEST_FILE)}
print(dict_I_call_matrix)



without_csv = [row.split(",")  for row in TEST_FILE] #...row in TEST_TEXT.split("\n")]

matrix = [row[1:] for row in without_csv]
labels = [row[0] for row in without_csv]
```